# Is that correct to say Team USA instead of USA Team?

Tags: vocabulary, learning

Is there any difference between saying: "The Team USA" and "The USA Team"?

Comment: Can you give more details about the context you saw the phrases in?

Comment: Are you asking about "Team USA" and "USA Team" (in the title) or "The Team USA" and "The USA Team" (body of the question)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a difference. One is correct and the other is not.

"The USA" is a proper noun, similar to "Spain" or "Congo" or "Russia." The *demonym* (word used to describe the nationality of a person or thing) is "American" or "Spanish" or "Congolese" or "Russian." The demonym is an adjective.

When the word comes *after* "Team" it means that "Team" is part of the actual name, so we capitalize it and use the noun without any article: "Team USA" or "Team Congo."

When the word comes *before* "team" it means that we are simply describing the team, not naming it; "team" is not capitalized and we use the adjective preceded by the definite article: "The American team" or "The Congolese team."

Comment: The difference between _Team USA_ and _USA Team_ is that the actual name is the first one. The position of _USA_ doesn't say which is the actual name, as there is an international youth soccer tournament called  _USA Cup_.